# Changing the size of a Qpixmap

Tags: pyqt5, qpixmap, resize-image

how i can change the size/shape of Qpixmap to receive a result like this?

original

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: It seems to be an image-processing issue rather than `pyqt5`! please see [affine transform](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html)

Comment: @Bilal Qt is able to do affine transformations, using [QTransform](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QTransform](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html) can create basic shape transformations, which can then be applied to [`QPixmap.transformed()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#transformed).

This specific case uses a "perspective" transformation, which uses projection and scaling information, and it's achieved using [`QTransform.quadToQuad()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#quadToQuad). Note that QTransform also provides `squareToQuad()`, but it's sometimes unreliable.

The important thing is to create two [QPolygonF](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpolygonf.html) instances, with the first based on the rectangle of the image, and the second with those corners at their "projected" points.

Note that creating a QPolygonF from a rectangle results in a polygon with 5 points, with the last one being the first in order to make it "closed". The QTransform `quadToQuad`, instead, requires a 4 points, so you have to remove the last point. Also note that the corners **must** be in the same order, so they will be: top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left.

In the following example, the perspective moves the top right corner at 20% of the height and the bottom right at the same opposite point (height - 80% of height).

```py
class ProjectionTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        source = QtGui.QPixmap('square.jpg')
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(pixmap=source))

        # the original rectangle of the image, as a QRectF (floating point)
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(source.rect())
        # the source polygon, ignoring the last point
        square = QtGui.QPolygonF(rect)[:4]
        # the "projected" square
        cone = QtGui.QPolygonF([
            rect.topLeft(), 
            QtCore.QPointF(rect.right(), rect.height() * .2), 
            QtCore.QPointF(rect.right(), rect.height() * .8), 
            rect.bottomLeft(), 
        ])
        transform = QtGui.QTransform()
        if QtGui.QTransform.quadToQuad(square, cone, transform):
            new = source.transformed(transform, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(pixmap=new))
```

And this is the final result:

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: THX,very good and detailed answer!